# vue.js - how to update JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, data-binding, vue.js

I lost in the basics of vue.js :/ I would like to add new column in html after click button, but I can't access to specific place in json.

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" v-for="row in json._children">
            <div class="col-xs-{{ col.size }}" v-for="col in row._children">
                <div v-for="module in col._children">
                    {{module.moduleType}}
                </div>
                <button v-on:click="addModule(col, $event)">Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        json: {
            'type': 'panel',
            '_children': [
                { 'type': 'row', '_children': [ { 'type': 'col', 'size': '2' }, { 'type': 'col', 'size': '10', '_children': [{ 'type': 'module', 'moduleType': 'HTML' }] } ] },
                { 'type': 'row', '_children': [ { 'type': 'col', 'size': '5' }, { 'type': 'col', 'size': '7' } ] }
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addModule: function(currentColumn, e) {
            // ????????
        }
    }
});
```

Can anybody help with this? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a column to a row, you should pass the row to `addModule()`. Shouldn't you?
Also, I pass the `$index` to know at which position to insert the new column:

```
<button v-on:click="addModule(row, $index, $event)">Add</button>
```

then all you have to do is [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) the new object into the row's `_children` array.

```
methods: {
    addModule: function(row, colIndex, e) {
        var newCol = { type: 'col', size: 1 }
        row._children.splice(colIndex, 0, newCol)
        //or to insert to the right:
        row._children.splice(colIndex + 1, 0, newCol) 
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! That's what I meant. Thank you very much!